# font-awesome font prevents clickable dropdown menu from working when clicked anywhere except on the outer edge of button?

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, font-awesome

Most buttons are meant to be easily clicked. The idea of a button is to have a simple, elegant way of getting around any web-page. It is one of humanities best inventions. But I have found a way to spoil it. For some reason, by adding a font awesome icon to a downdrop button menu, It makes the whole button stop working except for on the outer corner of it. Can anyone help me make the whole button work? What is going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-3x"></i></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem experienced can easily be solved. simply add a space, and then add your .dropbtn class to the icon class That is already there. Also, you will need to get rid of the fa-3x part. that is an added class member used to make the list icon bigger. but, you can also do that with a style="" that has a font-size of 3em.

When done, it should look something like this:

```
<i style="font-size: 3em;" class="fa fa-list-ul dropbtn"></i>
```